# php jquery sample not working if php tags used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tags

I am testing a jquery form [pop up](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form),

If I place it in a file pop.php,

with out `<? ... ?>` , just the html as in example, named php works fine

but if i use `<? ... ?>` ... it shows blank page,

so my file pop.php [showing blank]::

```
<?php
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


</body>
</html>
?>
```

what im I missing? thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding php tags when there is no php?

Comment: is a sample from a page where there is php, im just figuring out why is not working tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encapsulated your entire HTML page in PHP tags (old style at that - they should look like  for recent versions of PHP. You should only put those tags around PHP code not the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

set in `<?php  ?>` in new version by default short code `<? ?>` not work or go on setting to enable short code

**Update**

i have set a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/PJrp2/)**  in this it is working i think file link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

is creating problem  or see your php is install correctly

have your localhost working..?

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but I have changed beginning tag as you see in edited code, still blank example

Comment: i haven't used php for about 10 years haha, so i only use the php tags where i need php?

Comment: set some height or width in body or in  html like html,body{height:1000px,width:800px} for just a try to clear reset css issue doubt

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the new PHP tags (as recommended by Rituraj)
2. Any HTML / JS content between PHP tags would need to printed on the screen by way of using something like "echo" or print